# Cascading MySQL commit with Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

What I'm interested in is,

**Can you do a cascading(multi-model) commit?**

An example. I have models A, B and C.

I call a A->function(), which calls B->function() and then calls C->function(). Is there a way to make sure that both B,C and A are successful before I commit? I know, that I can do this for a single function, but what about cascading style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The db adapter transaction will work fine outside the models as long as it's controlled within the lifetime of the script.

```
$db->beginTransaction();

try {
    A->function();
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: A try / catch block with rollback in the catch looks so much neater

Comment: Fair enough Phil, I've updated my answer to reflect that. I was just considering that there may be other logic in A that didn't throw exceptions but thinking about it, if it's a model class it probably won't.

Answer (score 2):

Start transaction in A->function() and commit when C->function returns positive result. Otherwise rollback.

I can't see the problem. If results are as expected, return either them or true....